# Empty Collection View Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed 1 tutorial and i was able to fill a collectionView with some data(imageview and text):

```
let appleProducts = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "pug1"), UIImage(named: "pug2"), UIImage(named: "pug3"), UIImage(named: "pug4")]
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return appleProducts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.title?.text = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}
```

Now passing from the demo project to mine, I want to fill this CollectionView with data(Picture and text) that I get from FirebaseDatabse so I created this method:

```
struct item {
let pictureId: String!
let picture: String!
}
var items = [item]()
   func getLatestAddedItems(){
    self.items.removeAll()
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("Items").observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in

        //self.items.insert(item(picture: picture), at: 0)
        for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {

            let snap = childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot
            //print(snap.key)

            let picture = (snap.value as? NSDictionary)?["bookImage"] as? String ?? ""
            //print(picture)
            self.items.append(item(pictureId:snap.key, picture:picture))

        }
        print(self.items.count)


    })
}
```

And I create this button to call GetLatestAddedItems Method:

```
@IBAction func selectAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    getLatestAddedItems()
        }
```

And this one to check results:

```
@IBAction func gettableAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    print(self.items[0].picture)
    print(self.items[1].picture)
    print(self.items[2].picture)
    print(self.items.count)    }
```

OutPut results:

```
picture 1 link
picture 2 link
picture 3 link
3
```

Everythings look fine and correct, now after making required changes in ContentView methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return items.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    //cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
     let url = NSURL(string: items[indexPath.row].picture)
     let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)
     cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)

    cell.title?.text = self.items[indexPath.row].pictureId
    return cell

}
```

Now I'm getting an empty ContentView, the first time with button it works because I call the getLatestAddedItems() that will get and add data to the Items table, I try to call it in both ViewWillAppear or Viewdidload but nothings changes.

This is what I think the return items.count is returning 0 so nothings will appear any suggestions ?

Comment: Instead of observing your data by `value`, try observing data by `.childAdded`

Comment: Now I'm able to fill my CollectionView from firebase but only when I click a button that contain this code `self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your collectionView's **protocol delegation initialisation** to one of the *ViewController lifecycle scope* such as **`viewDidLoad()`** or **`viewWillAppear(_animated : Bool)`** if you are using a custom viewController(i.e embed a collectionView inside a viewController)

And reload your collectionView every time your user receives a value from its database.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

  self.collectionView.dataSource = self 
  self.collectionView.delegate = self 

 }

func getLatestAddedItems(){
 self.items.removeAll()
 let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
 databaseRef.child("Items").observe(.childAdded, with: {
    snapshot in

    for childSnap in snapshot.children.allObjects {

        let snap = childSnap as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let picture = (snap.value as? NSDictionary)?["bookImage"] as? String ?? ""
         self.items.append(item(pictureId:snap.key, picture:picture))
         print(self.items.count)
         self.collectionView.reloadData() 
     }
   })
}
```

***PS:-*** All the calls to your firebase server are asynchronous, which takes some time to retrieve the data from your FBDB, so put `print(self.items.count)` should be inside the **completionBlock** of the firebase observing call otherwise if it is put outside it will be called even before your data has been retrieved from FBDB.

Comment: it works now but i need to wait between 4-5 seconds to see pictures being loaded into my CollectionView , I call the method inside ViewWillAppear     `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        getLatestAddedItems()
        //getLatestAddedItems()
        //reloadbokks()
        CheckProfileIsCompleted()
    
    }` and I make the requested changes inside the **completionBlock**

Comment: You will have to ... Just like service that needs a backend to retrieve your data from. It takes time... *All the calls to your firebase server are asynchronous, which takes some time to retrieve the data from your FBDB*